# How change title of option menu and context menu in android?

Tags: android, menu, contextmenu, optionmenu

In my app i I have option menu and context menu which has English title. But i want to change that to the persian title with Farsi class that introduced in this topic:
[How can i write farsi (persian) in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874121/how-can-i-write-farsi-persian-in-android/21892120#21892120)

so how can i change the title?

Answer (score 0):

You should define your strings in a string file for Farsi and reference them using Android's resource ids.

Comment: please give me a example I'm new in android.